# Can not read shapes having a formula

Tags: python, python-pptx

If, there is a formula inside a shape such as a textbox, or a table - one cell of it
then the entire Shape is not read by Python-pptx library.

example textbox having formula:
[image: example textbox having formula]

```
prs = Presentation('file.pptx')

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
         print(shape.text)
         # Any of shape including a formula doesnt meet here
```

The code prints:

```
I am a normal sentence.
```

only.

How can I read any shapes which includes a formula?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code that read a shape from AlternateContent under ShapeTree, which choose the first shape as of it.

The shape having a formula have been wrapped in AlternateContent and python-pptx didn't read it.

The pull request is: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/pull/706